# If a function restriction to a dense subset of its domain is uniformly continuous, then there's an uniformly continuous extension of it

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $M,N$ be metric spaces such that $X \subset M$ is dense in $M$, $f:M \rightarrow N$ is continuous and $f|_X$ is uniformly continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

My proof:

We want to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta' > 0$ such that

$$
d(x,y) < \delta' \implies d(f(x),f(y))< \epsilon \quad \forall x,y \in M
$$

So let $\epsilon > 0$ and let’s find such $\delta' > 0$.

Since $f$ is continuous, then for every $x_0 \in M$ there is a $\delta_{x_0} > 0$ such that

$$
d(x,x_0) < \delta_{x_0} \implies d(f(x),f(x_0)) < \epsilon/3 \quad \forall x \in M
$$

Since $f|_X$ is uniformly continuous then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$
d(\hat x,\hat y) < \delta \implies d(f|_X(\hat x),f|_X(\hat y)) < \epsilon/3 \quad \forall \hat x,\hat y \in X
$$

Now let $x,y \in M$. Take $\hat x, \hat y \in X$ such that

- $d(x,\hat x) < \min \{\delta/3, \delta_{\hat x}\}$
- $d(y,\hat y) < \min \{\delta/3, \delta_{\hat y}\}$

From that, we get that

- $d(f(x),f_X(\hat x)) < \epsilon / 3$
- $d(f(y),f_X(\hat y)) < \epsilon / 3$

Then, if $d(x,y) < \underbrace{\delta / 3}_{\delta'}$ we get that

$$
d(\hat x, \hat y) \leq d(\hat x, x) + d(x, y) + d(\hat y,y) \leq 3\cdot \delta/3 = \delta
$$

which implies that

$$
d(f|_X(\hat x),f|_X(\hat y)) < \epsilon/3
$$

therefore

$$
d(f(x),f(y)) \leq d(f(x),f_X(\hat x)) + d(f_X(\hat x),f_X(\hat y)) + d(f_X(\hat y),f(y)) \leq 3 \cdot \epsilon/3 = \epsilon
$$

---

I took a more than expected to reach this solution. I'm satisfied with it, but still not 100% sure of my work. Can someone please check my work so far? Thanks!

Comment: I think $d(x,y) < \delta'$ in the fifth line. And what is $x'$ in $d(x, x') < \min\{ ...\}$? In the above line, you said "Now let $x, y \in M$... ". Can I choose arbitrary $x$ and $y$ of $M$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuous function that is uniformly continuous on a dense subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561656/continuous-function-that-is-uniformly-continuous-on-a-dense-subset)

Comment: @with-forest yes, it was indeed $\delta'$ and instead of $x'$ and $y'$, I meant $\hat x$ and $\hat y$. Fixed those. Thanks. An yes, you can choose any $x, y \in M$ as long as $d(x,y) < \delta' = \delta/3$

Comment: @LostinSpace Yep, it's pretty much the same...

Comment: It is correct. I think it is better to notice that $d(x,y) < \delta / 3 $ first. For example, "Now let $x,y \in M$, and assume that $d(x,y) < \delta /3 ... $.

Comment: And I think,  in $\min \{ \delta/3 , \delta_{\hat{x}} \}$, the last term should be changed as $\delta_x$.

Comment: @with-forest I agree with your first comment, that would make it clear. Thanks! But I don't see why I should change $\delta_{\hat x}$ to $\delta_x$. You meant to change the notation?

Comment: Roughly speaking, I explain the situation in words. there is two points $x$ and $y$ in $M$ whose distance is less than $\delta / 3$. And since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is dense, there is $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ very close to $x$ and $y$ (respectively) such that their value under $f$ is similar and $\hat{x}, \hat{y} \in X$. In this situation, the distance between $x$ and $\hat{x}$ is depends on $x$ not on $\hat{x}$.

Comment: @with-forest, ok. makes sense, I agree that the distance depends on $x$ and not on $\hat x$, therefore a better notation would be $\delta_x$. Thanks :)